# How to get glyph widths by parsing a TTF font file?

Tags: fonts, binary, truetype, glyph

For capturing the glyph widths of a `TrueType` font, I convert the corresponding `TTF` file by `fontforge` into `AFM`, which is in text format (not binary). Then, parsing the text file to capture the glyph widths.

There should be easier way to directly parse the binary `TTF` file to capture the glyph widths.

I appreciate a strategy for shell script or C, but any programming language is OK, as the idea is the key, and codes can be adapted.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you mean *advance widths*, what you're interested in is the [hmtx table](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/otspec/hmtx.htm). It's fairly straightforward to parse, as you can see the structure is:

```
typedef struct  _longHorMetric {
    USHORT  advanceWidth;
    SHORT       lsb;
}  longHorMetric;
```

Of course, in order to parse the hmtx, you'll also need to know in general [how to locate font tables](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/otspec/otff.htm), and you'll also need the [numberOfHMetrics](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/otspec/hhea.htm) value from the hhea table and the font's [numGlyphs](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/otspec/maxp.htm) from the maxp table. The structure of all of these is given in the links and should be fairly easy to parse in any language.

Comment: What is the unit of `advanceWidth`? Font Unit? What is the font unit?