# Truncate given text to specific width, for a specific font

Tags: php, fonts

I want to truncate specific text, to specific width. I know the font I'll be using and the font size. I'm trying to figure which is the best approach to tackle this problem. **This has to be done serverside**.

As far as I'm aware of there's no function in PHP that outputs the width of each character. I could use image* functions, but I don't want to create images, only for the purpose of determining the width of the given text.

An obvious solution that comes to my mind is to create a magic widths table, as: a - 16px, b - 14px, etc. but that sound horrendous (and obviously I won't be able to go through entire scope of characters given text has).

Another solution that comes to my mind is convert TTF to json through Cufón, and then use that reference file to truncate given text, but again this sounds like a roundabout way of doing things. If I remember correctly Cufón (and other converters) use Batik to generate the SVG reference, and using that as a step is out of the question as well.

Do I have to write my own implementation of [hmtx table parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18330464/how-to-get-glyph-widths-by-parsing-a-ttf-font-file) in PHP, or is there some implementation I can use?

Comment: Won't the font be "applied" clientside and so be enlarged, not be used at all, ...?

Comment: The purpose of this is either to output "smartly" truncated results for Google results, or to warn the admin that the SEO title that he's putting in goes outside the width that Google uses (certain width depending upon the client, using Arial 16). While the second one **can** be done clientside, the first one can not.

Comment: Is this in some kind of closed or otherwise carefully controlled system where you can make assumptions about how the font will actually render on the client?

Comment: @djangodude please see the comment above on what is the purpose of this. If I know the font and its size why shouldn't I be able to calculate the width of the bounding box - accessing the glyphs is the problem.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I understand what you're trying to do. That's not what I asked. To help you figure out a solution I want to know whether you are sure that you can rely on the font being rendered the same on the client as it is on the server. In my experience it is not a reliable assumption at all, unless you have very carefully-controlled/known clients.

Comment: @djangodude while I don't know how fonts "work", I assume each glyph has its width set within TTF file. Google specified that what they're outputting in the results is 482px. Let's assume that all the browsers output the text with the same dimensions (as, letter spacing and glyph widths are the same between the browsers) or differences between the browsers don't matter (I don't need to be exact)

Comment: For the most part, your assumption is correct about the width within the TTF file. But the assumption that all browsers output the text with the same dimensions is not: there are differences in the font rendering engines among the various platforms and even among browsers on a single platform which can affect the dimensions (sometimes quite significantly). You didn't mention originally that you don't need to be exact, which is a pretty big detail, but I think there's a way to get close enough to what you need (see my answer, coming shortly).

Comment: @djangodude out of curiosity - how big are the differences? While the differences of few pixels virtually don't matter for me (and that's why I omitted it), differences of "W is twice the size in IE, what are we going to do about it" kind of do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59759/discussion-between-djangodude-and-eithedog).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to djanodude's answer, but GD library also has the same capabilities, and GD is often installed on PHP servers.

The function you need is `imagettfbbox` (Image Bounding Box for TTF fonts). http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettfbbox.php

This gives you the corners of the text from a given TrueType font (in pixels) and from here you can work out the pixels on screen.

Same limitations as mentioned in djanodude's answer regarding slight differences between server and client. Another gotcha is that the True Type fonts may not be the same as you will be reading a TTF you put on the server which may be different from the one one on the client computer.

Another warning: GD library can be memory hungry. You might want to cache your results (to save unnecessary processing) and user `ini_set('memory_limit','128M');` if you run itno problems.

Answer (score 3):

If you can make use of [ImageMagick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) in your PHP installation, [Imagick::queryFontMetrics](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.queryfontmetrics.php) (and a few other related font functions) should do the trick for you. The example on the linked page does pretty much exactly what you are after: basically, you set the font & size, then pass a string in to queryFontMetrics. It returns a number of metrics, one of which is textWidth, which you can use to determine whether you're within your specified width or not.

You may need to make a few passes over a given string to get it right. It is important to use a full string, though (as opposed to simply adding up widths of characters) because data inside of the font can cause differences between the width of, say "AV" compared to the summed widths of 'A' and 'V'.

As I mentioned in the comments, there can also be differences between your server versus clients on the various platforms and browsers, so I would recommend incorporating some kind of error tolerance, particularly at smaller font sizes where the differences are likely to be exaggerated.

Comment: I don't think I can - while it's not a big deal (as I can request IM to be installed), I won't close the question just yet (I don't want to install IM on the server, specifically for this functionality). Otherwise - yup, that's exactly the thing I'm searching for.