# Finding glyph width in C# (private font)

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, fonts

In order to embed a font in a PDF, one needs to determine a set of glyph widths (for inclusion in the metadata). In order to make the calculations about the page area consumed by text as it flows, one needs to know the same information.

I am considering using C# on a web server to generate PDF documents. The fonts are not (and cannot be) installed; they can be loaded from TTF files/streams. I need to know how much of the "page" is going to be used so that I can handle text overflow correctly, and also need to provide the glyph widths if the font is to be embedded.

`System.Drawing.Text.PrivateFontCollection` can get me the "cell"'s ascent/descent and line spacing, which is useful for the vertical calculation, but I also need to make a horizontal calculation.

Is there a way to access a private (i.e. non-installed) font's glyph widths from C# without resorting to this: 
[How to get glyph widths by parsing a TTF font file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18330464/how-to-get-glyph-widths-by-parsing-a-ttf-font-file)

Comment: Usually one uses a PDF library to create PDF documents. Any decent general purpose PDF library can extract the required data from fonts you provide as files or streams. No need, therefore, to rack one's brain over this...

Comment: I've not seen a free one in .NET that allows me to control the flow (and re-flow) of text to this level of precision. And the question is valid regardless of output file implementation (which doesn't have to be PDF - that's just my example case).

Comment: So what you are saying is you don't need the PDF tag... As for your question: the linked question is indeed how it's done. I fail to see what's so "resort to" about it.

Comment: The PDF tag is not necessary but it is intended to help this question reach a wider audience seeing as someone who's solved it for PDF may have an answer. As for "resorting", I don't want to constrain the solution to TrueType fonts and hmtx tables. Since asking the question I have discovered the GlyphTypeface which offers me about 60% of the answer.

Comment: *"I've not seen a free one in .NET that allows me to control the flow..."* - well, I was not aware of special requirements in that direction. In that case I wish you luck that you don't step into the pitfalls pdf creator software often steps into.  ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GlyphTypeface class in System.Windows.Media (PresentationCore.dll) provides access to the advance widths in fractions of an em. PDF font descriptors require widths as integers in thousandths of an em.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Media; // requires PresentationCore.dll

namespace ConsoleAppFontMetrics
{
    internal class Metrics
    {
        internal static void PrintWidths(string path)
        {
            var ffs = Fonts.GetFontFamilies(path);
            foreach (var ff in ffs)
            {
                foreach (var t in ff.GetTypefaces())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(t.Style);
                    if (t.TryGetGlyphTypeface(out GlyphTypeface gt))
                    {
                        foreach (var ctg in gt.CharacterToGlyphMap)
                        {
                            var width = (int)Math.Round(gt.AdvanceWidths[ctg.Value] * 1000);

                            Console.WriteLine($"{(char)ctg.Key} ({ctg.Key}) Width = {width}");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Running the above code for my TrueType font gives me this:

```
Normal
a (97) Width = 1160
b (98) Width = 1663
c (99) Width = 2065
```

The output matches the metadata inside a previously exported PDF (from another program) with the font embedded.

```
8 0 obj
<<
/Type/Font
/Subtype/TrueType
/Name/F2
/BaseFont/XXXXXX
/FontDescriptor 7 0 R
/FirstChar 97
/LastChar 99
/Widths[1160 1663 2065]
>>
endobj
```